# is there a proper way to compose URL in Swift?

Tags: swift, url

I'd like to understand if there Is a "golden standard" for assembling urls, someone told me this is an "elegant" way to do it. I think it is better since using the + with (strings), but it is THE way? (I know maybe there are multiple ways in iwich it works, but I'd like to be sure how I should do it, and possibly why)

```
  public static func listOfServiceURL(codeCompany: String?) -> URL? {
    
    let codeCompany = codeCompany ?? "N/A" //"DEFAULT"

    let base = URLUtility.basicUrl[App.shared.environment] ?? "N/A"
    let device = URLUtility.basicDevice[App.shared.environment] ?? "N/A"
    let name = UserSettingsManager.shared.name
    
    var urlHolder = "{base}{device}{codeCompany}/{name}"
    
    urlHolder = urlHolder.replacingOccurrences(of: "{base}", with: base)
    urlHolder = urlHolder.replacingOccurrences(of: "{device}", with: device)
    urlHolder = urlHolder.replacingOccurrences(of: "{codeCompany}", with: codeCompany)
    urlHolder = urlHolder.replacingOccurrences(of: "{name}", with: name)


    let url = URL(string: urlHolder)

    return url
        
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at the `URLComponents` struct

Comment: Why all those `replacingOccurrences`? Why not simply `let urlHolder = "\(base)\(device)\(codeCompany)/\(name)"`? And why is `codeCompany` optional?

Comment: in a recent project, they told me it is not "elegant" and not the "proper and standard way".

Comment: This *is* the proper way to concatenate strings to a path, if all items are separated by slashes consider `appendingPathComponent`.

Comment: my senior TM corrected me, so I had to change this way, but I was not happy. it is optional since it could be absent

Comment: All the "N/A" occurrences make less sense than declaring `codeCompany` as non- optional. From the practice perspective you are going to assemble an URL including the `codeCompany`. The compiler will tell you at **compile time** if one of the parts is missing. For example a "N/A" `basicUrl` will create an URL but it's invalid.

Comment: so, should I use "if let" or guard statement?

Comment: Yes, you should, but I don't understand all those optionals anyway. In Swift optionals are not a synonym for *don't care* like `nil` in Objective-C.

Comment: they are there only since data retrieved ad dicts, so is derived by the structure for "replacements" lousy they should become     guard let device = URLUtility.basicDevice[App.shared.environment] else {return /*what, URL() ?? */}

Comment: A good start would be if URLUtility could produce a URL object directly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A way to create the URL (or return `nil`) is

```
public static func listOfServiceURL(codeCompany: String?) -> URL? {
    
    guard let codeCompany = codeCompany,
        let base = URLUtility.basicUrl[App.shared.environment],
        let device = URLUtility.basicDevice[App.shared.environment] else { return nil }
    let name = UserSettingsManager.shared.name
    
    let urlHolder = "\(base)\(device)\(codeCompany)/\(name)"
    return URL(string: urlHolder)
}
```

String Interpolation is a ***proper and standard way*** to concatenate strings in Swift

---

Or – still more reliable – with `URLComponents`

```
public static func listOfServiceURL(codeCompany: String?) -> URL? {
    
    guard let codeCompany = codeCompany,
        let base = URLUtility.basicUrl[App.shared.environment],
        let device = URLUtility.basicDevice[App.shared.environment],
        let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: base) else { return nil }
    
    let name = UserSettingsManager.shared.name
    urlComponents.path = device + codeCompany
    return urlComponents.url?.appendingPathComponent(name)
}
```

Comment: “String Interpolation is a proper and standard way to concatenate strings in Swift” But it is not a correct way to form a URL.